# Being rejected time after time

Tags: resume, job-search, applications

My job applications are rejected every single time, be it in a top level company or a less renowned one. I am not even offered an interview be it an application for a full-time job or an internship. I have reviewed my resume several times and even asked professionals to review it. Most of the time the reason being a lack of experience in a full-time company. I am a graduate and have undertaken several research jobs at the university that have turned out to be some really good contributions to the field along with journal publications. How do the companies expect us to have (or gain) an experience when they are not ready to offer a job to the newbie. What should I do to have them offer me an interview let alone the job?

Comment: Great. Reject this as well.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the Workplace. We answer specific situations, questions like "What should I do" are not practical answerable questions. Please take the Tour to understand how we function.

Comment: I guarantee I have been rejected more times than you, over 1000 times.  It's a numbers game, just keep plugging away.

Comment: @RichardU Not great advice. When it comes to flat-out rejections like OP is describing the issue is quality, not quantity. OP should apply to jobs he is suited for, which is presumably what he isn't doing. How you determine that has been discussed on this site and elsewhere many times before.

Comment: Are you applying for entry level jobs?

Comment: @JasonJ Yes and I am pretty sure I am applying for the jobs I am suited for.

Comment: You're not really asking a question that can be answered ... just keep networking and putting yourself out there. Sometimes unpaid activities can lead to job offers.

Comment: @Lilienthal worked for me.

Comment: I have no idea what you have done and not done. You claim there is nothing wrong with your resume - okay. Is it possible that your cover letters are crap? You seem to think highly of yourself - perhaps we all should think highly of ourselves. Unfortunately, your opinion is not shared by the lowest-level HR who get to read your resume first. Or is it possible that your resume never went past the word parser? Voting to close because we have no data to work with.

Comment: @RichardU I'm sure buying a lottery ticket every week for years paid off for the people who won but that doesn't make it a sound financial investment. Throw enough mud at the wall and some of it will stick.

Comment: @Lilienthal persistence is my best weapon.  It's how I came back from being crippled and homeless.

Comment: You can't win the lottery unless you play.  Likewise, if you quit applying for jobs, you're not likely to find one.  What exactly are you two arguing about?

Comment: @RichardU I'm not saying it didn't work for you. If you apply for a thousand jobs I'm sure that eventually you'll run into someone who's desperate or incompetent enough to hire the first person to come along. Or you'll get lucky and end up applying for a job that you actually qualify for. My point is that such a shotgun approach is counter-productive for anything except unskilled labour. You can apply for a million lawyer jobs but you're never going to be hired if you don't have legal experience or training.

Comment: This question was closed just as I was about to post my answer, so I'll post it as a comment.  It might be that a few potential employers see the publications on your CV and assume that you're either mostly interested in academia and would leave them as soon as you get an opportunity there, or wouldn't fit into a corporate environment. I'm not telling you to leave the publications off, as they show valuable skills. But it might help to clarify that you're looking for a position in *industry*. You can do this in your cover letter, or in a statement of purpose at the top of your CV.

Comment: Also, based on those publications, you probably have some lecturers or researchers at your school who think highly of you. Get in touch with them! Let them know you've been having trouble getting interviews, and ask if they know anyone who's hiring. When I graduated from college, it was also a difficult time to look for a job because companies only wanted people with experience. But I found my first job because one of my lecturers put me in touch with some companies who might be interested in my skills.

Comment: Also consider going to job fairs, if they have them in your area. That will give you an opportunity to talk to someone (usually an HR person) rather than just sending them a CV. Tell everyone you know that you're job hunting. And if you know someone who works at a company that you'd like to work for, get in touch with them. You don't have to ask them for a job (which might make both of you feel awkward). Instead, ask them if they know of any companies that might be interested in your skills.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of things that you may need to do:

1. Your CV clearly isn't selling your skills
2. You need to flesh out your research jobs as these should suffice as "Work Experience"
3. Are you tailoring covering letters/CV's for each role?

If you are getting flat out rejections for jobs then your application is not selling yourself. You cite that experience is coming up, well that means the roles you are applying for aren't junior enough, or that there is a lack of jobs in the field so more experienced people are applying for junior jobs.

You need to sell your research jobs better, you need a better CV and you need some luck. The first hurdle is usually the hardest one to jump.

Can you give an indication as to what field you are working in? It may allow others to offer industry specific advice?

Comment: I belong to the Biomedical engineering field.

Answer (score 3):

> Most of the time the reason being a lack of experience in a full-time
>   company.

This would indicate that you are targeting the wrong jobs. Instead, look for jobs that are truly entry-level, and thus don't require any experience in a full-time company. You might need to widen your target.

> I am a graduate and have undertaken several research jobs at the
>   university that have turned out to be some really good contributions
>   to the field along with journal publications.

So that gives you some obvious networking possibilities with research project advisors and coworkers. Often, the best jobs come through your personal network, not through just responding to job ads.

> How do the companies expect us to have (or gain) an experience when
>   they are not ready to offer a job to the newbie.

For companies that don't want to hire newbies, that's not their problem - it's your problem. Instead, find companies willing to hire new graduates. Your college placement office can usually help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're a recent graduate (within the last year) and in the US for this answer.

> What should I do to have them offer me an interview let alone the job?

You can't force them to offer an interview or a job, but like others have stated you can sell yourself better in order to get the interview or job.

I'd suggest turning to your university for networking, job postings, and help. Universities want their students to be successful and find jobs. Do they offer any networking events where employers come to the campus? These are great events to hand someone your resume IN PERSON and make a personable impression!

Many schools have a careers website with job postings. These postings are clearly looking for entry-level employees or willing to hire new graduates with little to no experience. At my university, the business school students were very aware of this site but I found most other majors outside of the school of business had no idea it even existed, so I'd check and see if there is such a thing.

Also, your university may have a career help center where you can sit with an adviser and go through your resume and CV with you line by line and even word by word. They will usually have great resources for you in numerous aspects of finding a job.

It can be rough and take time but you will find a job! Good luck!